# How do I access the array of third column collectly in C programming?

Tags: arrays, c

I have written a code in C to calculate the Daily Value, DV (in %). Firstly, I need to convert the data from ounce to gram from an input file.
[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76tXz.pngig)
1st column: Cereal Name
2nd column: Carbohydrate
3rd column: Protein
4th Column: Fat

I have no problem with this section. Here is my code to do the conversion from ounce to gram by multiplying 28.35.

```
float* ozToG(float array[10][3]){
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    

        for(int j=0; j<3 ;j++){
        
        array[i][j]*=28.35;
        }
        
        //printf("%f %f %f\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2] );
    
    }
    
    return &array[0][0];
}
```

Then I shall need to calculate the DV by dividing each nutrient by the recommended value, ie carbohydrate = 300g, protein = 50g and fat = 65g. I have also written my user-defined function code for this section.

```
void percentage(float* array, int* carbohydrate_avg, int* protein_avg, int* fat_avg){
    
double sum_carbohydrate = 0, sum_protein = 0, sum_fat = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        
        *(array+3*i+0)= *(array+3*i+0)*100/300;
        *(array+3*i+1)= *(array+3*i+1)*(100/50);    
        *(array+3*i+2)= *(array+3*i+2)*(100/65);
                
        sum_carbohydrate += *(array+3*i+0);
        *carbohydrate_avg = sum_carbohydrate/(float)SIZE;
        
        sum_protein += *(array+3*i+1);
        *protein_avg = sum_protein/(float)SIZE;
        
        sum_fat += *(array+3*i+2);
        *fat_avg = sum_fat/(float)SIZE;
    }
    
}
```

[Output calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yviyJ.png)
This is the output that I have obtained.

For example: In the second column and second row, the output shows 24.9%. It is obtained by using 2.64x28.35/300x100.

However, I have a logical error with my last column, fat when calculating its DV. I should get 15.9% instead of 10.2%, which is just the answer in gram. It is unable to perform DV calculation for fat. I have tested my conversion function and it seems that it is correct. Hence, the only problem is in my DV function. Can someone point out the problem?

Comment: Perhaps `(100/35)` should be `(100/35f)`. The former does integer division while the latter does floating point division.

Comment: @Spikatrix, thank you. The problem is solved now.